# Getting the coordinates of the mouse-hovered character in an HTML pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an HTML `<pre>` tag with some multi line content in it and be able to calculate the column (X) and row (Y) of the character that I am currently hovering with the mouse.

So far I am using the following approach, but it does not work on all browsers:

I attach an event listener to the `<pre>`'s "onpointermove" event and divide the event's clientX and clientY coordinates by the size of a single character. However, I could not find a portable way to calculate the character size (accounting also for any possible spacing), so I am using hardcoded values as can be seen in the JS below. This leads to incorrectly calculated values - the further I am from the upper left corner, the bigger the error.

Any suggestions how to make this portable across different browsers?

If necessary, I can CSS style the `<pre>` element.

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Relevant code is here:
// Obviously, the current character size calculation is not portable

var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

var charSizeX = isFirefox ? 8.0 : 7.8; // I guessed those values by trial and error
var charSizeY = isFirefox ? 17.0 : 15.0;

/////////////////////////////////////////

function onpointermove(event) {
    var mouse_x = event.clientX/charSizeX;
    var mouse_y = event.clientY/charSizeY;

    mouse_x = Math.round(mouse_x * 100) / 100;
    mouse_y = Math.round(mouse_y * 100) / 100;

    document.getElementById('mouse').innerHTML = 'Mouse pos: x = ' + mouse_x + ', y = ' + mouse_y;
};

var screen = document.getElementById('screen');
screen.addEventListener('pointermove', onpointermove);
```

```css
// could potentially use css to style the "screen"
#screen {
    // ?
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<pre id="screen">................
................
................
................
...some.........
................
......random....
................
................
..content.......
................
.......here.....
................
..........123...
................
................</pre>

<br><div id="mouse"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to figure out what letter your mouse is hovering over within the `pre` element, simply have each letter tell you if it's being hovered over.

Text is rendered as strings in the DOM. What we need to do is this:

- convert the **Text** to an **Array of Characters**.
- convert each **Character** to an **Element**
- replace the original **Text** with **Elements**
- apply a **pointermove** event to each **Element**

```js
function ScreenTextGrid(screen) {
  
  // HELPER FUNCTIONS

  // Create a SPAN with additional properties
  function TextElement(partial) {
    return Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), partial);
  }

  // Transform Object Array to SPAN elements
  function rowsToElements(row) {
    return row.map(TextElement);
  }

  // Apply a Grid Closure
  function Grid(fn) {
    this.grid = { row: 0, column: 0 };
    return fn.bind(this);
  }

  // Use Grid Closure to create Object Array with Grid Properties
  function TextAndCoordinates(acc, txt, ind) {
  return "\n" === txt || !ind ? 
    ( grid.row++, grid.column = 0, acc.push(ind ? [] : [{ textContent: txt, row: grid.row, column: grid.column++ }]), acc ) 
  : 
  ( acc[acc.length - 1].push({textContent: txt,row: grid.row,column: grid.column++}), acc );
}

  // Clear out Screen
  // Append Text Elements
  // Apply event handler to each Element
  function apply(screen, elements, onHover) {
    screen.innerHTML = "";

    elements.forEach(function (row, column) {
      if (column > 0) screen.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

      row.forEach(function (element) {
        screen.appendChild(element).addEventListener("pointermove", onHover || function () {});
      });
    });
  }

  // Event Listener for Hover
  function handleTextHover(event) {
    var my = event.currentTarget;
    var x = my.column,
        y = my.row,
        char = my.textContent;

    console.log("x: " + x, "y: " + y, "character: " + char);
  }
  
  
  // SETUP
  var screenText = screen.textContent,
      screenArray = Array.from(screenText),
      screenGrid = screenArray.reduce(Grid(TextAndCoordinates), []),
      screenElements = screenGrid.map(rowsToElements);

  // WORK
  apply(screen, screenElements, handleTextHover);
}

ScreenTextGrid(document.getElementById("screen"));
```

```css
// could potentially use css to style the "screen"
#screen {
  // ?
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <pre id="screen">................
................
................
................
...some.........
................
......random....
................
................
..content.......
................
.......here.....
................
..........123...
................
................</pre>

  <br>
  <div id="mouse"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This might be exactly what I need - I'll definitely give it a go. Can you speculate if I should expect any additional CPU utilization while hovering if the grid was filling my entire screen? I guess no, but maybe you have better insight. Asking, because in the original method, the calculation was a simple division.

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov the only way to optimize this more that I can think of is to use event delegation on the `pre` element. When an item is hovered it's not calculating anything at all. All of the work is done in the initial setup and that information is saved on the DOM node. When you then hover the element it doesn't do anything but read the data(column and row/x and y respectively) as it exists on that Node.

Comment: Thanks again for the proposed solution. I ended up using a different solution because it was easier for me to implement: inside the <pre>, I create a <span> element with a single char and use getBoundingClientRect() to get it's precise dimensions. Either way, your approach totally makes sense and I accepted it.